# Narrowing down a QuerySet in Django by using difference() and/or exclude()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to narrow down a QuerySet in Django. I'm trying to do this by excluding (or taking the difference of) another QuerySet.

I've already tried using `difference()` and `exclude()` but both of them do not work for some reason. Besides, I’m confused by the error messages I get.

Here’s the code:

```
ipdb> all_products
<QuerySet [<Product: P1>, <Product:  P2>, <Product: P3>, <Product: P4>, <Product: P5>, <Product: P6>]

ipdb> added_products
<QuerySet [<Product: P1>, <Product:  P2>, <Product: P3>]

ipdb> all_products.exclude(added_products)
*** ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

ipdb> all_products.difference(added_products)
*** django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by doc the [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)  you should given lookup parameters, try to use `pk__in`

```
all_products.exclude(pk__in=added_products)
```

more details [querysets in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. This works for me. Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: glad to help you, don't forget to read the docs by links and accept the answer for other who will search the same.

Comment: I will definitely do those too. Best. :)